# Using multiple aggregate functions - sum and count

Tags: sql-server

I've tried several of the solutions to my question on the site but could not find one that worked. Please help!
Other than taking some liberties with the report_names, the data is realistic of what I am trying to accomplish and is just a small portion of what I am up against, roughly 97K rows of data with the same type of repetition of branch, file_count, report_name...the file numbers are unique and are insignificant. It is for informational purposes of my question and explains why the amounts are unique - they are tied to the file_name
I am looking for one report_name with the sum of the two amounts.

Here are the current results to my query:

```
branch    file_count file_volume   net_profit  report_name    file_number
Northeast 1          $200,000.00  $200,000.00  bogart.hump.new      12345
Northeast 1          $195,000.00  $197,837.00  bogart.hump.new      23456
Northeast 1          $111,500.00  $113,172.00  bogart.hump.new      34567
Northwest 1           $66,000.00   -$1,500.18  jolie.angela.new     45678
Northwest 1          $159,856.00   -$2,745.58  jolie.angela.new     56789
Northwest 1          $140,998.00   -$2,421.69  jolie.angela.new     67890
Southwest 1           $74,000.00   $73,904.00  Man.bat.net          78901
Southwest 1          $186,245.00   -$4,231.25  Man.bat.net          89012
Southwest 1           $72,375.00   $73,641.00  Man.bat.net          90123
Southeast 1           $79,575.00    -$1,821.76 zep.led.new          1234A
Southeast 1          $268,600.00   $268,600.00 zep.led.new          2345A
Southeast 1           $77,103.00    -$1,751.68 zep.led.new          3456A
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
branch    file_count file_volume    net_profit  report_name     file_number
Northeast 3          $506,500.00   $511,009.00  bogart.hump.new 
Northwest 3          $366,854.00    -$6,667.45  jolie.angela.new 
Southwest 3          $332,620.00   $143,313.75  Man.bat.net 
Southeast 3          $425,278.00   $265,026.56  zep.led.new
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
branch,
count(filenumber) AS file_count,
sum(fileAmount) AS file_amount, 
sum(netprofit*-1) AS net_profit,
concat(d2.lastname,'.',d2.firstname,'.','new') AS report_name,

FROM user.summary u
inner join user.db1 d1 ON d1.loaname = u.loaname 
inner join user.db2 d2 ON d2.cn = u.loaname

WHERE d2.filedate = '2015-09-01'
AND filenumber is not null

GROUP BY branch,concat(d2.lastname,'.',d2.firstname,'.','new')
```

Comment: What is the question and what is the problem?

Comment: why not `sum(netprofit) * -1 AS net_profit`.. everything looks ok.. have a feeling you're leaving some information out since your `query` doesnt match your `current results`

Comment: Why even multiply by -1 at all?  looks to be a simple summation to me.  aside from that everything looks like it should give you the desired results.

Comment: My question is, how do I get from the current results to the "what I am looking for" - basically summing the file_volume and net_profit and counting the file_count into one row for each report_name. Regarding the -1 multiplyer, you are correct - this is not needed.

Comment: Based on what you have provided (Data set, report, query), you should achieve the results you want.  I'm not understanding the problem and really want to help you.

Comment: There is no way, given what you've shown, to get a report name ending with 'net' as you've shown in both, what you get and what you want. Also, the query that you say is producing what you get does not have a column file_number in it's output. If you are including 'file_number' in the group by to get it in the results, it will cause you problems. Remove it or use window functions instead of aggregate functions for the counts and sums.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue i see with your current query is that you have a comma at the end of this line that would give you a syntax error:

```
concat(d2.lastname,'.',d2.firstname,'.','new') AS report_name,
```

If you want the blank field `file_number` as shown in your desired result set though, you could leave the comma and follow it with the blank field by adding to it:

```
concat(d2.lastname,'.',d2.firstname,'.','new') AS report_name,
'' file_number
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but could not have done it without airing it out in this forum. In my **actual query**, I included the "file_name" column, so I had both the "count(file_name)" and "file_name" columns...but in my query example, I only had the "count(file_name)" column. When I removed the "file_column" column from my actual query, it worked. Side note...it was obvious that I excluded a key component in my query. On any future query questions, I will include the complete query but substitute actual column names with col1, col2, db1, db2, etc... thanks very much for responding to my question.